# php empty data record deletion

Tags: php, html, jquery

There is no problem when the form is sent normally, but when I click on the add-phone button with jquery, input
I have an inpute with name sub_phone_ and when I post it, it is saved in the content named sub_email, sub_map and sub_maps which I did not add to the database in php. I want that if there are no email map maps inputs, they should not write them in the database.

database record

```
[{"title":"1","address":"1","phone":"1","submenu":[{"email":"1","phone":null,"map":null,"maps":null}]}]
```

```
if empty
"phone":null,"map":null,"maps":null <<< delete.
```

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" class="formify">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="iletisim">
        <div id="menus">
            <ul id="menu" class="menu">
                <li>
                    <div class="menu-item">
                        <a href="#" class="delete-menu">
                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">title</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="title">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">address</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="address[]" cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="address""></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Phone</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone[]" placeholder="Phone">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                <ul class="menu"></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn add-email" data-background-color="warning">Add Email</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn add-phone" data-background-color="warning">Add Phone</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn add-map" data-background-color="warning">Add Map</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-btn">
    <button type="submit" value="1" name="submit" >Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.add-email', function (e) {
    var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $(this).prevAll('.sub-menu:last').find('ul').append('<li>\n' +
        '<div class="handle"></div><div class="menu-item">\n' +
        '   <a href="#" class="delete-menu">\n' +
        '       <i class="fa fa-times"></i>\n' +
        '   </a>\n' +
        '   <div class="row">\n' +
        '       <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">İletişim Maili</label>\n' +
        '           <div class="col-sm-7">\n' +
        '               <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">\n' +
        '                   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_email_' + index + '[]" '
        + 'placeholder="İletişim Maili">\n' +
        '                </div>\n' +
        '            </div>\n' +
        '        </div>\n' +
        '    </div>\n' +
        '</li>');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(document.body).on('click', '.add-phone', function (e) {
    var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $(this).prevAll('.sub-menu:last').find('ul').append('<li>\n' +
        '<div class="handle"></div><div class="menu-item">\n' +
        '<a href="#" class="delete-menu">\n' +
        '   <i class="fa fa-times"></i>\n' +
        '</a>\n' +
        '   <div class="row">\n' +
        '       <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">İletişim 2. Telefon</label>\n' +
        '           <div class="col-sm-7">\n' +
        '               <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">\n' +
        '                   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_phone_' + index + '[]" '
                    + 'placeholder="İletişim 2. Telefon">\n' +
        '               </div>\n' +
        '           </div>\n' +
        '       </div>\n' +
        '   </div>\n' +
        '</li>');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(document.body).on('click', '.add-map', function (e) {
    var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $(this).prevAll('.sub-menu:last').find('ul').append('<li>\n' +
        '<div class="handle"></div><div class="menu-item">\n' +
        '    <a href="#" class="delete-menu">\n' +
        '        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>\n' +
        '    </a>\n' +
        '   <div class="row">\n' +
        '       <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Yol Tarifi URL Adresi</label>\n' +
        '       <div class="col-sm-7">\n' +
        '           <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">\n' +
        '               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_map_' + index + '[]" '
                    + 'placeholder="Yol Tarifi URL Adresi">\n' +
        
        '            </div>\n' +
        '        </div>\n' +
        '     </div>\n' +
        '  </div>\n' +
        '</li>');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(document.body).on('click', '.add-maps', function (e) {
    var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $(this).prevAll('.sub-menu:last').find('ul').append('<li>\n' +
        '<div class="handle"></div><div class="menu-item">\n' +
        '   <a href="#" class="delete-menu">\n' +
        '       <i class="fa fa-times"></i>\n' +
        '   </a>\n' +
        '   <div class="row">\n' +
        '       <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Map Görseli URL Adresi</label>\n' +
        '       <div class="col-sm-7">\n' +
        '           <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">\n' +
        '               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_maps_' + index + '[]" '
                    + 'placeholder="Map Görseli URL Adresi">\n' +
        '           </div>\n' +
        '       </div>\n' +
        '   </div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</li>');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

PHP

```
if (post('submit')) {

    $menu = [];
    $menu_title = post('menu_title');
    if (!$menu_title) {
        $error = 'Menü Başlığını Belirtin!';
    } elseif (count(array_filter(post('title'))) == 0) {
        $error = 'En Az Bir Menü İçeriği Girmeniz Gerekiyor!';
    } else {

        $address = post('address');
        $phone = post('phone');
        foreach (post('title') as $key => $title) {
            $arr = [
                'title' => $title,
                'address' => $address[$key],
                'phone' => $phone[$key],
            ];
            if (post('sub_email_' . $key)) {
                $submenu = [];
                $subphone = post('sub_phone_' . $key);
                $submap = post('sub_map_'.$key);
                $submaps = post('sub_maps_'.$key);
                foreach (post('sub_email_' . $key) as $k => $subemail) {
                    $submenu[] = [
                        'email' => $subemail,
                        'phone' => $subphone[$k],
                        'map' => $submap[$k],
                        'maps' => $submaps[$k]

                    ];
                }

                $arr['submenu'] = $submenu;
            }
            $menu[] = $arr;
        }

        $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO menu SET menu_title = :menu_title, menu_content = :menu_content');
        $result = $query->execute([
            'menu_title' => $menu_title,
            'menu_content' => json_encode($menu)
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try following code.

```
  foreach (post('title') as $key => $title) {
        $arr = [
            'title' => $title,
            'address' => $address[$key],
            'phone' => $phone[$key],
        ];
        if (post('sub_email_' . $key) != null) {
            if (post('sub_email_' . $key)) {
                $submenu = [];
                $subphone = post('sub_phone_' . $key);
                $submap = post('sub_map_' . $key);
                $submaps = post('sub_maps_' . $key);
                foreach (post('sub_email_' . $key) as $k => $subemail) {
                    if (($subphone[$k] != null) && ($submap[$k] != null) && ($submaps[$k] != null)) {
                        $submenu[] = [
                            'email' => $subemail,
                            'phone' => $subphone[$k],
                            'map' => $submap[$k],
                            'maps' => $submaps[$k]
                        ];
                    }
                }
                if (count($submenu) > 0) {
                    $arr['submenu'] = $submenu;
                }
            }
        }

        $menu[] = $arr;
    }

    $result=DB::table('menu')
          ->insert([
            'menu_title' =>$menu_title,//your menu title here
            'menu_content' => json_encode($menu)  
          ]);
```

I hope it's works for you.

Comment: when I try the way you do, submenu never saves.

Comment: i have edited my answer so you can try again and if this is also not working for you than please add comment so i can help you.

Comment: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in \add-menu.php on line 32
error line
  if (($subphone[$k] != null) && ($submap[$k] != null) && ($submaps[$k] != null))

Comment: you should keep frontend validation to avoid this type of error i.e. the number of sub_email must be equal to the number of sub_phone and so on.